# Custom user auth - Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration, django-login

I've been trying to write a **custom_user app** to **register**/**login** with **email** and **password**.
I followed a tutorial, but I must have left something out of my code, since I'm able to register a new user (it is created, I checked in the admin panel), but I can only login with the superuser created in the terminal with the "manage.py createsuperuser" function.

I don't know if I'm making a mistake on the registration code or on the login code.
Anyway,this is my **models.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = datetime.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True, null=True)
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    second_name  = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    address1     = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    address2     = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    area_code    = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=datetime.now())
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

This is **forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from models import CustomUser, CustomUserManager


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and password.
    """

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "second_name",)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    """
    A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on the user, but replaces the password field with admin's password hash display field.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "second_name",)
```

And this is the **views.py** file

```
def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True

            return redirect('../')

        else:
            print user_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered})

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

Is there anything I could do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to log in with a username or email? Your `auth_view` is confusing in that regard. Also you have a model field `username`, but specify `email` as your `USERNAME_FIELD`...

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm able to login with the email, but only using the superuser one that I have created in the terminal

Comment: And I'd like to login using the email